# How to Display Specific User information in cakephp..?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Iam new to cakephp and i have a problem with an element. how to display each user account information when ever the user loggedin than click on myaccount link how will show the particular user details. myaccount link is in element.

Finally How to display specific user information when click on the myaccount link. The myaccount link is in element file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the logged In users information in their account page.Then you simply do it by using Session. Cause in CakePHP logged in user's are stored into session.

In this case you can try `var_dump($this->Session->read('Auth.User'));`, here you can see the logged in users information. And now you can populate users information form it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want login user data then, After your successfully login your user data will be store in Auth User session.

So if you want to fetch whole user data then you can try var_dump($this->Session->read('Auth.User'));

Or

If you want any single field from your login user table then you can use like,
$this->Auth->user('id')

here instead of 'id' you can use any field name of users(where you store your user credentials and details) table.

Make sure your login user data stored in the authentication table i.e if you are storing only username and password in users table and the other details stored in another table with name user_details, then you can not fetch user_details for the login user.

for that you need to store user_details in Auth.User session after login.

I hope this will be helpful for you.